How to set elements and their values in local storage using a class selector , querySelectorAll?
I am trying to make a to do list and right now when I press on the add task button 2 inputs and 1 select element are being created and displayed on the page.I save the content and display it and its just the nodelist string
I know querySelectorAll gives a nodeList and local storage only stores strings.
How can I make the nodeList appear as the HTML elements and their values instead of the nodelist string?
My broken code:
//Implementing local storage
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
//Save sct1taskTable into localStorage
sct1SaveToLocalStorageBtn.addEventListener("click",() => {
        const taskTableContent = document.querySelectorAll(".task-table-child");
        localStorage.setItem("taskTableContentKey",taskTableContent);
        alert("Content saved :D");

})
//Retrieve sct1taskTable into localStorage
sct1LoadFromLocalStorageBtn.addEventListener("click",() => {
        const loadedTaskTableContent = localStorage.getItem("taskTableContentKey");
        sct1taskTable.innerHTML = loadedTaskTableContent;
        alert("Content loaded :D")
})
});


You either need to store the HTML representation of the element(s), or the data that allows you to re-create the elements dynamically.

document.querySelectorAll(".task-table-child") will retrieve an array-like-object whose elements are all elements that match your selector of ".task-table-child" at the time you called it. To convert all these into HTML string, you could do something like this:


console.log([...document.querySelectorAll(".task-table-child")].map(item => item.outerHTML).join(""))
<div class="parent">
    <div class="task-table-child"><p>something</p></div>
    <div class="task-table-child"><p>something else</p></div>
</div>



I have queried your elements, converted the array-like-object into an actual array via the [...<something here>] operator and called map on the array to replace the items with their outerHTML (you could use innerHTML instead if you prefer) and then converted it into a string via .join(""). So, you could do something like
localStorage.setItem("taskTableContentKey",[...document.querySelectorAll(".task-table-child")].map(item => item.outerHTML).join(""));

Loading things back would look like
const loadedTaskTableContent = localStorage.getItem("taskTableContentKey"); 

and then you can write this wherever you want.

You can change your approach. Your goal is to store the to-do list data and then restore it.This data doesn't necessarily have to be HTML nodes; it can be an object. When you restore the nodes, use the stored object data to recreate the nodes.
sct1SaveToLocalStorageBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const taskTableContent = document.querySelectorAll(".task-table-child").map((el) => el.innerText);
  localStorage.setItem("taskTableContentKey", taskTableContent);
  alert("Content saved :D");

})
//Retrieve sct1taskTable into localStorage
sct1LoadFromLocalStorageBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const loadedTaskTableContent = localStorage.getItem("taskTableContentKey");
  loadedTaskTableContent.forEach((text) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = text;

    sct1taskTable.append(div);
  })

  alert("Content loaded :D")
})


I think I understand the approach but when trying to run the app with this code , I get this error message thrown out:
TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement. (yoHub.js:56:89)
